# Logstash filter for Cisco ASA

Tags: logstash-grok

Could you please help me with the following log message?

```
`%ASA-4-106100: access-list acl_ID {permitted | denied | est-allowed} protocol       interface_name/source_address(source_port) (idfw_user, sg_info) interface_name/dest_address(dest_port) idfw_user, sg_info) hit-cnt number ({first hit | number-second interval}) hash codes`
```

Here's a real example:

```
`%ASA-4-106100: access-list acl_ID {permitted | denied | est-allowed} protocol       interface_name/source_address(source_port) (idfw_user, sg_info) interface_name/dest_address(dest_port) idfw_user, sg_info) hit-cnt number ({first hit | number-second interval}) hash codes`
```

My task is to analyze traffic that matches a specific ACL_ID. For this purpose, I want Logstash to extract log events with the specified ACL_ID and hash codes, and then store the following values from the log into an index: source_address (without the port) and dest_address (with dest_port). However, I'm having trouble understanding the filters. Could you please help me write them?

Answer (score 0):

I can make it :)

```
input {
  udp {
    port => 9001
  }
}

filter {
  if "0xf736ab35" in [message] {
    grok {
      match => {
        "message" => "%{DATA:tag}-%{INT:severity}-%{INT:code}: %{WORD:action}-list %{DATA:access_list} %{WORD:src_interface}/%{IP:src_ip}\(%{NUMBER:src_port}\) ->%{DATA:dst_interface}/%{IP:dst_ip}\(%{NUMBER:dst_port}"
      }
    }
         mutate {
      remove_field => [ "tag", "severity", "code", "action", "access_list", "src_interface", "dst_interface", "hit_action", "hit_count", "first_hit", "hit_values"]
    }
}
}

output {
 if "0xf736ab35" in [message] {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts    => "https://localhost:9200"
            index    => "asa"
            user => "elastic"
            password => "password"
            cacert => "/etc/logstash/certs/http_ca.crt"
        }
```

after in elastic:

```
GET ready/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique_combinations": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          { "src_ip": { "terms": { "field": "src_ip.keyword" } } },
          { "dst_ip": { "terms": { "field": "dst_ip.keyword" } } },
          { "dst_port": { "terms": { "field": "dst_port.keyword" } } }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

after i run output from elastic and run script python

```
import json

def transform_combinations(output_file):
    with open('output.json', 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)

    combinations = data['aggregations']['unique_combinations']['buckets']

    with open(output_file, 'w') as file:
        for index, combination in enumerate(combinations, start=1):
            src_ip = combination['key']['src_ip']
            dst_ip = combination['key']['dst_ip']
            dst_port = combination['key']['dst_port']
            line = f"{index}) {src_ip} > {dst_ip}:{dst_port}\n"
            file.write(line)

output_file = 'result.txt'
transform_combinations(output_file)
print(f"Transformation completed. The result is saved in '{output_file}'.")
```

result olooks like this

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat result.txt
1) 192.168.1.13 > 10.1.2.1:23
2) 192.168.1.13 > 10.1.2.1:343
3) 192.168.1.133 > 10.1.2.1:123
4) 192.168.1.133 > 10.1.2.1:222
5) 192.168.1.133 > 10.1.2.1:231
6) 192.168.1.133 > 10.1.2.1:3123
7) 192.168.1.133 > 10.1.2.1:343
```